# Maven corrupting binary files in src/main/resources when building jar

Tags: java, maven, dll

I've got an issue with a maven project where I am distributing dlls from the src/main/resources/lib folder.

The project is built as a single jar with dependencies using the maven-assembly-plugin.

Unfortunately, the maven process is corrupting my dll libraries during the copy process so that they are no longer useful to the application.

I've had a look at such concepts as resource filtering.

Here's my relevant pom.xml

Does anyone have any ideas?

I think I need to do something like this but so far it's not working for me.

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>

                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib</directory>
                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>

                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>de.bochumuniruhr.psy.bio.behaviourcoder.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

**My final solution (based on the answers below):**

Thank you for the great answers. I ended up going with the answer that doesn't require extending the configuration of the maven-resources-plugin. I placed my binary files in the `src/main/resources/unfiltered-resources` folder as I needed to filter my other resources.

Here is a link to the [source code](https://github.com/johndeverall/BehaviourCoder).

Below is my final working pom at the time of writing.

```
<build>
        <finalName>BehaviourCoder_${git.build.time}_${git.commit.id.describe-short}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/unfiltered-resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                    <injectAllReactorProjects>true</injectAllReactorProjects>
                    <dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss</dateFormat>
                    <dateFormatTimeZone>UTC</dateFormatTimeZone>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>de.bochumuniruhr.psy.bio.behaviourcoder.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This part:

```
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
```

Should be under under the `<build/>` section like this:

```
 <project>
      <build>
          <resources>
              <resource>
                  <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
              </resource>
          </resources>
          <plugins>
              ...
          </plugins>
      </build>
 </project>
```

Answer (score 6):

When assembly plugin kicks in it is already too late, as the resources were already copied by maven resources plugin. You should exclude filtering on earlier phase (when the resources are being copied to target folder by maven resource plugin).

See maven's docs how to do this: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/binaries-filtering.html

For your case this can be something like:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>dll</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: This properly fixed my resource files being corrupted. Excluding the folder from filtering simply flattens the folder which is not what I want because it breaks resource loading for me. This retains my resource directories while not corrupting my resource files.